# Creating PointCut for all classes extending an abstract class

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have two Classes

com.home.learn.TryImpl1 &

com.home.learn.TryImpl2

which extends a abstract class com.home.learn.Try.

I created a Aspect in spring as

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="pointcut" expression="execution(* com.home.learn.Try.*(..))" />
    <aop:aspect ref="aopDemo">
        <aop:around method="around" pointcut-ref="pointcut" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'try' defined in file [C:\Users\admin\workspace\Spring_Aspect_pure_pojo\spring-learn.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setInterceptDuringConstruction(Z)V
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setInterceptDuringConstruction(Z)V
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:429)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:68)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Can anyone please help?
I want to watch all methods in all classes which extend the abstract class com.home.learn.Try

Comment: can you check if it works by renaming "Try" to something else?

Answer (score 2):

`<aop:pointcut id="pointcut" expression="execution(* com.home.learn.Try+.*(..))" />`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'try' defined in file [C:\Users\admin\workspace\Spring_Aspect_pure_pojo\spring-learn.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setInterceptDuringConstruction(Z)V
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setInterceptDuringConstruction(Z)V

Comment: Aravind can you paste the stacktrace in the question with some formatting?

Comment: Hey again. Been on vacation so haven't checked in for a while. Did you solve this? It looks from the stacktrace like you might have missed to include the cglib library (or have a bad version of it) in your project classpath. If you are using maven:       <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>